# In Entity Framework Core, what is the difference between using InvariantGlobalization and not using it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses Entity Framework Core repository.

My actual version is Entity Framework Core 7 and I have set in the `.csproj` file of the ASP.NET Core project, this the option `InvariantGlobalization` to false.

Now, I am trying to migrate to .NET 8, and now, when I run a query in Entity Framework Core, I get this error:

> Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
> en-us is an invalid culture identifier.

If I set the parameter `InvariantGlobalization` to true in the ASP.NET Core project, then it works.

My installation is Spanish culture, and it seems according to the error, that it is related with the en-us culture.

Which is the difference between to set the parameter to true and false? Why does it work with .NET 7 and now with .NET 8 I have to change this value? How could it affect to the behaviour of the application?

Thanks.